# What advice would you offer somebody who is building a laundry chute for the first time?

Tags: drywall, ceiling, renovation

I'm looking to build a laundry chute from our bedroom closet to the laundry room below. The positioning is such that the wall of our closet is shared with a storage closet in the loft above our garage. The floor of our closet is above the laundry room. I've figured out where I would need to cut to place the chute to where we'd want the laundry to fall.

What should I keep in mind when cutting into the wall (in the closet) and the ceiling (in the laundry room)? I'm seeking any general advice in renovation or anything specific to help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Safety first

Make sure you wear proper safety gear. Safety goggles, appropriate gloves, hearing protection (if applicable), and a hardhat, might all be useful safety equipment.

## Watch out for that...

Make sure you know what is inside the wall/floor, cutting through a wire or pipe can ruin your day really fast.

## "Did it come out yet?"

It might be a good idea to line the chute using ducting or other lining material, so the items you drop in actually make it out the bottom.

## Don't bring down the house

The easiest and safest place to install a laundry chute is between studs/joists. If you have to cut studs/joists to install the chute, you'll have to reinforce the structure appropriately. If you are going down more that a single floor, you'll likely have some structural issues to deal with. If you go between studs, you'll have to deal with a sill plate at the bottom of the wall and possibly a top plate at the top of the wall below.

## The right tool for the job

Make sure you have all the **proper** tools before you begin. Having all the right tools you need at hand, makes every job easier.

Comment: good advice Tester. Stay between the structural members.

Comment: Also, put some type of safety cover on the hole to keep small children and pets from falling in !!!!!!!! That is unless they are wicked dirty and need a wash.  lol